# How to join threads of an asyncio executor runned inside coroutine?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-asyncio

My webapp uses aiohttp, and executes analyses on separate threads. I would `join()` all the executor threads at exit. `executor.shutdown(wait=True)` seems to not work, if threads are started inside a coroutine.

This is not my real code, but an example:

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import atexit
import signal
import time
import os


def atexitHandler():
    try:
        executor.shutdown(wait=True)
    except Exception:
        pass

    for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
        try:
            loop.call_soon_threadsafe(task.cancel)
        except Exception:
            pass

    try:
        loop.stop()
    except Exception:
        pass

    print("'Bye")

def analysis():
    print("analysis started")
    time.sleep(10)
    print("analysis finished")


@asyncio.coroutine
def analysis_coro(loop, executor):
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.run_in_executor, executor, analysis)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

loop.add_signal_handler(
    signal.SIGTERM | signal.SIGINT | signal.SIGQUIT, 
    atexitHandler
)

cores_num = os.cpu_count() or 1
executor = executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=cores_num)

try:
    loop.run_until_complete(analysis_coro(loop, executor))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    atexitHandler()
```

On the contrary, if I run directly `loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.run_in_executor, executor, analysis)` and do `loop.run_forever()`, it works without problems.

PS: I'm stuck python 3.4 because of CentOS 6.5 (I can't use a compiled version)

Comment: The code example seems bigger than necessary to show the point, confusing the readers. Also, what's the purpose of this "loop2 = loop" code block?

Comment: @hdiogenes: To check if loop variable is defined, see the try.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. What's the point of "checking" it if you just ignore the error?

Comment: @hdiogenes: to not inform the user about an error that is expected. Anyway the check is indeed superflous, since `loop` is used inside `try` statements only, so I remove it.